# Random moving divs via jQuery, HTML, CSS

Tags: jquery, random, position, directions

I am creating a game where you have to follow particles (divs) and click on them to "eat" them. The issue I am having currently is that I can't find a way to clone each div and give it a random X and Y coordinate value to position it.

Here is my code:

```
var x = e.pageX;
var y = e.pageY;

function reposition(div, x, y, randomMode) {

      if(randomMode == 1) {
        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 990);
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 560);
      }

      $(div).animate({"left": x + "px"}, "slow");
      $(div).animate({"top": y + "px"}, "slow");
    }

    // need to find some way to duplicate the divs and move them in random directions

    setInterval(function() {
            for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

              reposition("#grabItem", 0, 0, 1);
            }
          }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
//select all grab items, and since there will be multiple particles
//use a class to mark them, not an ID. This line is to capture all
//particles existing in the markup, that are not dynamically added later
var $particles = $('.grabItem');
//set your container that has all the particles
var $container = $('body');

//every two seconds add a new particle at random location
setInterval(function() {
   for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
      $particles.add(CreateParticle());
      MoveParticles();
   }
}, 2000);

//creates a new particle and adds to the canvas
function CreateParticle(){
   return $('<div/>').addClass('grabItem').appendTo($container);
}

//randomly moves all the particles around
function MoveParticles() {
   $particles.each(function() {
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 990);
      var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 560);

      $(div).animate({"left": x + "px"}, "slow");
      $(div).animate({"top": y + "px"}, "slow");
   });
}
```

That will add a new particle at a random location every two seconds and move all existing particles around (including the new one). If you need an exact clone method check out jQuery's [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. However, I am a bit confused with what you did inside `CreateParticles()`... What is `$('<div/>')` there for? BTW, I think you meant "`</div>`".

Comment: @klftw I did not mean `</div>` the code I posted is what I meant. If you send in an empty element to the jQuery constructor (like a self closing `div` tag) it creates a new DOM object for that element. Then you need to append it to the actual DOM via an `.append()` or `.appendTo()` or similar call.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a [Clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method in jQuery, is it what you are looking for?